# Регистрация пользователя со слабым паролем

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно кто то уже прошел этот путь и нашел ответ:

Как в связке Wordpress + Woocommerce разрешить при регистрации использование "слабого" пароля?

Есть вариант полностью отключить password-strength-meter в functions.php но это очень плохое решение т.к. позволяет регистрироваться вообще без пароля либо с паролем из одного символа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, плагин - WC Password Strength Settings

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimum-password-strength/

Судя по описанию, он позволяет регулировать требуемую сложность пароля.